# Syntax error in postgresql query coded in python

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

I am executing PostgreSQL13 queries coding them in python 3.9 using the psycopg2 library. I also am working with PostGIS extension over PostgreSQL.

Kindly look for the comment which points out the line which causes the syntax error. I am having trouble both understanding what is the syntax error and how to debug it since I need to execute PostgreSQL queries using python so any tips will be greatly appreciated.

```py
def corefunc(rf, openConnection):
    pcur = openConnection.cursor(name="pcur" + rf)
    rcur = openConnection.cursor(name="rcur" + rf)
    acur = openConnection.cursor()
    rcur.execute("SELECT geom FROM " + rf)
    
    for number in range (1, 5):
        acur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "pf"+ rf)
        acur.execute("CREATE TABLE " + "pf" + rf + " (index integer, sums integer)")
        pcur.execute("SELECT geom FROM " + "pf" + str(number))
        row = 1
        for each in rcur.fetchall():
            if number == 1: acur.execute("INSERT INTO " + "pf" + rf + " (index, sums) VALUES (" + str(row) + ",0)")
            for eachone in pcur.fetchall():
#-------------------------------------------- the statement below gives the syntax error
                acur.execute("UPDATE TABLE " + "pf" + rf + " SET sums = sums + "\
                    +"ST_Contains(" + " ' " + each[0] + " ' " + ", " + " ' " + eachone[0] + " ' " + ")::int WHERE index = " + str(row))
            row = row + 1


def parallelJoin (pointsTable, rectsTable, outputTable, outputPath, openConnection):
    #Implement ParallelJoin Here.
    cursor = openConnection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + pointsTable)
    size_data = (cursor.fetchall())[0][0]
    for number in range(1, 5):
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pf" + str(number))    
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE pf" + str(number) + " AS SELECT * FROM "
                        + pointsTable + " LIMIT " + str(size_data/4)
                        + " OFFSET " + str(((number-1)*size_data)/4))
    
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + rectsTable)
    size_rects = (cursor.fetchall())[0][0]
    for number in range(1, 5):
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rf" + str(number))    
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE rf" + str(number) + " AS SELECT * FROM "
                        + pointsTable + " LIMIT " + str(size_rects/4)
                        + " OFFSET " + str(((number - 1) * size_rects)/4))
    threads = dict()
    for number in range(0, 4):
        threads[number] = threading.Thread(target=corefunc, args=("rf" + str(number + 1), openConnection))
        threads[number].start()
        break
    
    while threads[0].is_alive() or threads[1].is_alive()\
            or threads[2].is_alive() or threads[3].is_alive(): pass
    
    # more shit to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just thought checking out the syntax from somewhere and I found the problem. To update table, the query begins with "UPDATE...." not "UPDATE TABLE.....".